# Django get data in serializer from two steps away related table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the below models:

```
class Campaign(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SubTopic(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CampaignSubTopicAssn(Base):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name='subtopic_assn', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtopic = models.ForeignKey(SubTopic, related_name='campaign_assn',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('campaign', 'subtopic')
```

```
class CampaignSubTopicAssnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = org_models.ContextualCampaignSubTopicAssn
        fields = ['subtopic']
```

In my campaign serializer I want to fetch all the `subtopic_ids` and their `display_name` as well:
currently this serializer just gives the ids and not the name, basically the table is two steps away in relation.

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    subtopic_assn = CampaignSubTopicAssnSerializer(many=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the `Subtopic` fields and call it in your `CampaignSubTopicAssnSerializer` as shown below.

```
class CampaignSubTopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubTopic
        fields = ['id', 'name' ]

class CampaignSubTopicAssnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subtopic = CampaignSubTopicSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = CampaignSubTopicAssn
        fields = ['subtopic' ]
```

This will give result as shown below. hope this is what you are expecting.

[image]

or you can try the below code :

```
class CampaignSubTopicAssnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subtopic_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='subtopic.id')
    subtopic_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='subtopic.name')
    class Meta:
        model = CampaignSubTopicAssn
        fields = ['subtopic_id','subtopic_name' ]
```

where you can change `subtopic_id`, `subtopic_name` as per your requirement

Comment: The first method worked well thanks a lot! Can you elaborate what is passed in the source parameter 'subtopic.id'
what is ```subtopic``` here?

Comment: subtopic is the field in CampaignSubTopicAssn model. since it is a foreign key we can access it's fields using id, name, display_name